MongoDB Atlas cannot be connected from WSL2 Node js
I'm Using Ubuntu on WSL2. Following error is shown when i try to connect to mongoDB atlas using mongoose. It can connect from windows successfully but doesn't do so from WSL2.
> mernapp@1.0.0 dev
> nodemon backend/server.js

[nodemon] 3.1.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node backend/server.js`
Server started at http://localhost:5000
/home/anupam/myprojects/mernapp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:909
    err = new ServerSelectionError();
          ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
    at _handleConnectionErrors (/home/anupam/myprojects/mernapp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:909:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (/home/anupam/myprojects/mernapp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:860:11)
    at async connectDB (file:///home/anupam/myprojects/mernapp/backend/config/db.js:7:22) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'cluster0-shard-00-02.8gyal.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'cluster0-shard-00-02.8gyal.mongodb.net:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        minRoundTripTime: 0,
        lastUpdateTime: 19156669,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
            at connectionFailureError (/home/anupam/myprojects/mernapp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:356:20)
            at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/home/anupam/myprojects/mernapp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:272:44)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
          [cause]: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
              at connResetException (node:internal/errors:718:14)
              at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (node:_tls_wrap:1600:19)
              at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)
              at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
              at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
            code: 'ECONNRESET',
            path: undefined,
            host: 'cluster0-shard-00-02.8gyal.mongodb.net',
            port: 27017,
            localAddress: undefined
          }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        maxMessageSizeBytes: null,
        maxWriteBatchSize: null,
        maxBsonObjectSize: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      },
      'cluster0-shard-00-01.8gyal.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'cluster0-shard-00-01.8gyal.mongodb.net:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        minRoundTripTime: 0,
        lastUpdateTime: 19157949,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: AggregateError has an empty errors array. Please check the `cause` property for more information.
            at connectionFailureError (/home/anupam/myprojects/mernapp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:356:20)
            at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/home/anupam/myprojects/mernapp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:272:44)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
          [cause]: AggregateError
              at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1074:18)
              at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1558:3)
              at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:566:11)
              at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
            code: undefined,
            [errors]: []
          }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        maxMessageSizeBytes: null,
        maxWriteBatchSize: null,
        maxBsonObjectSize: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      },
      'cluster0-shard-00-00.8gyal.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'cluster0-shard-00-00.8gyal.mongodb.net:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        minRoundTripTime: 0,
        lastUpdateTime: 19158355,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
            at connectionFailureError (/home/anupam/myprojects/mernapp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:356:20)
            at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/home/anupam/myprojects/mernapp/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:272:44)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
          [cause]: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
              at connResetException (node:internal/errors:718:14)
              at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (node:_tls_wrap:1600:19)
              at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)
              at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
              at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
            code: 'ECONNRESET',
            path: undefined,
            host: 'cluster0-shard-00-00.8gyal.mongodb.net',
            port: 27017,
            localAddress: undefined
          }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        maxMessageSizeBytes: null,
        maxWriteBatchSize: null,
        maxBsonObjectSize: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-3dvuer-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}

Node.js v18.13.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Following is the code that is throwing the error
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

export const connectDB = async () => {
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
        console.log(conn);
    // } catch (error) {
    //    console.log(error) ;
    //    process.exit(1); // process code: code means exit with failure, 0 mean success
    // }
}

enter image description here
I've set the network access to all and also disabled WSL vEthernet firewall.
The same code when copied to windows directory runs and connects successfully.
Solved::
I think it was node permission issue. I uninstalled node on my distro and then reinstalled both nvm and node and it worked.

I don't have any trouble connection from node inside WSL to Atlas.  If you edit the question to add in some code and the full error message, we may be able to help.

I've edited my comments to include both full error message and the code that caused the error. I called connectDB() inside app.listen

Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established usually indicates either the client side is not using TLS or the server rejected the client certificate.  What does that MONGO_URI look like?

mongodb+srv://:@cluster0.8gyal.mongodb.net?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0

I also think it might be a permission issue as the first time i ran the server in my windows machine it asked for some UAC permission (i guess didn't pay much attention) for Node Runtime? But none of that has been asked while running the server from wsl2.
